# eclipse oxygen update issue after upgrading from neon to oxgen

Tags: eclipse

After upgrading my eclipse neon to eclipse oxygen, when I attempt to check for updates now, I get an error as follows:

"Cannot complete the request. This installation has not been configured properly for Software Updates.  See the error log for details"

Error log entry is as follows:

Could not location running profile instance.  The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be setup correctly in the config.ini"

Here are those entries in the config.ini:

eclipse.p2.profile=file:/opt/eclipse-oxygen/eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=file:/home/wendell/.p2/

Any idea what is going on??